# php check function return

Tags: php, function, return

I have a function which return a loop, now I want to check if this function returns null or empty

That's the function:

```
function getCopy($pname){
    function listCopy($block) {
        foreach ($block as $b) {

            echo  '<div class="copy">'.$b->getBlock().'</div>'. "\n";
        }
    }
    $filter=array(
    new DFC(classContent::FIELD_PNAME, $pname, DFC::CONTAINS),
    new DFC(classContent::FIELD_TYPE, 'copy', DFC::CONTAINS),
    );
    $block=classContent::findByFilter(conn(), $filter);
    return listCopy($block);
}
```

That's my logic:

```
if( isset (getCopy($pname)) ){
    echo "<label for='copy'>Copy</label><br>"
    ."<textarea name='copy' id='copy' rows='10' cols='60'>".getCopy($pname)
    ."</textarea><br>";
}
```

The `isset` doesn't work and neither `if(getCopy($pname) != '')` does.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Mauro

Comment: Kind of silly to actually call getCopy() twice isn't it? If getCopy() returns a value for $pname, then call it again with the same argument to display the returned value that you've already calculated once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "return a loop" from a function. You can only return values. The `listCopy` function does not return anything, it just outputs. Hence `getCopy` doesn't return anything either. Defining a function within a function is usually bad practice as well, you won't be able to call `getCopy` twice in your case.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Thanks deceze! I used a different approach now, it was very messy! thanks 4 opening my eyes :)

Answer (score 2):

use [empty](http://be.php.net/empty) or [is_null](http://be.php.net/is_null) or a combination of both.

Or you could just negate the check by doing `if( !getCopy($pname) ) ){ ... }` but i'd go with any of the two functions above.

Edit: as deceze noted, you can't directly evaluate the return value with `empty`, you'll have to assign it to a var first and then pass that var to `empty()`

```
$result = getCopy($pname);
if(empty($result)) { ... }
```

Comment: You can't use `empty` or `isset` to check function return values.

Comment: You only need `empty` when checking potentially non-existing variables. For function return values `if (getCopy())` or `if (!getCopy())` is just fine.

Comment: Calling functions as an argument in `empty()` is now supported in PHP. You will not need to assign it to a variable first in versions 5.5+. For example: `if(empty(getCopy($pname))) { . . . }` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The php function `isset()`is used to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. So it's normal that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`empty()` is what you are looking for but bare in mind these two points:

1. You shouldn't declare functions within functions.
2. Your function will never return something, it's always *void* since you don't `return` anything. So `empty()` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: You can't use `empty` to check function return values.

Comment: @deceze: Indeed, he has to assign the return values to a variable first.

Comment: Or he can just use `!`. `empty` is simply `!isset($foo) || !$foo`, and you don't need the first part here since the function certainly exists.